# How to find out where docker disk image is residing when it's taking up too much space

Tags: docker

I have a docker disk image size of 75 GB available, and it's almost all used up.  Despite the tutorials out there I can't quite wrap my head around where that size is being taken up.

[image]

I've pruned everything I can seem to prune, and ran system df with the following results:

[image]

Obviously that's not 73 GB.

I do have to continually retrieve and swap databases out, but I delete them locally as they're synced to my DB container.  However, I believe it's each time that I do this that causes the image to grow.

Any other tricks or tips in reducing my disk size? Thanks in advance.